# Flex how to scroll a RichEditableText without shaking

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%" id="chatScroller">
    <s:RichEditableText
    id="mainChat"
    textFlow="{TextConverter.importToFlow(text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT)}"
    selectionHighlighting="always"
    selectable="false"
    focusedTextSelectionColor="#32EB28"
    unfocusedTextSelectionColor="#32EB28"
    editable="false"
    lineHeight="25"
    styleName="chatWin"
    fontSize="10"
    paddingTop="20"
    paddingBottom="20"
    height="100%"
    width="461">
        <s:TextFlow >
        </s:TextFlow>
    </s:RichEditableText>
</s:Scroller>
```

I'am updating the `text` variable, so for this I've added this event:

```
chatScroller.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, scrollBottom);

        private function scrollBottom(e:FlexEvent):void {

                chatScroller.verticalScrollBar.value = chatScroller.verticalScrollBar.maximum;
        }
```

and it works, BUT the textarea firstly goes top, and then goes at the bottom, so this makes a shaking effect that happens fast, how could I avoid this and make the scroller, to scroll at bottom without going top before it goes bottom? please help can't find any solution

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add `chatScroller.validateNow();` immediately after you change the text.